# Coded UI and the old ways to test web app

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, browser-automation

My project used to use Microsoft.mshtml and SHDocVw.dll to automate our Web UI test. Then I heard about the CodedUI test. So questions are:

- Does it mean I can give away Microsoft.mshtml and SHDocVw.dll?
- And is there any connection/difference between CodedUI and Microsoft.mshtml and
  SHDocVw.dll?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your existing automation tool have an application with a browser inside it?  That is how I've seen SHDocVw.dll used before.  The tests would be able to interact with the web pages' DOM and a lot can be accomplished that way.  You are, of course, limited to IE, which I believe is also the case with Coded UI.

Coded UI is able to test applications and IE, as I recall.  So you should be able to use Coded UI to test against your old test app, but it wouldn't really make sense.

Unfortunately, I think you will lose your existing test code if you move to Coded UI, but you will have a larger community to run ideas by, etc.

I don't think Coded UI uses SHDocVw.dll, because it interacts with the IE itself, not a form that has a 'browser control' inside it.

If you don't need cross browser coverage and you don't mind rewriting your existing tests, then CodedUI would be a good choice, in my opinion, to get away from a custom solution.